# flex embedded in html on ubuntu using cherrypy

Tags: apache-flex, cherrypy, mxmlc

I'm trying to open an SWF file i created using mxmlc but when i open it in the browser it just shows a white page, and if i embed it into html it shows the grey background ... and when i try to open the html file from localhost (using cherrypy) it just says
`Error #2046`
and the server shows nothing wrong .. the message appears only in the client

I'm using ubuntu 10.10 and running mxmlc from the terminal.
note: it used to work a couple of minuets ago, i don't know what happened ... i tried to undo changes and no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a Runtime Shared Library related error:

> This error indicates that the loaded
>   RSL was not signed properly. In the
>   case of framework RSLs, the
>   framework's SWZ file that the
>   application attempted to load at run
>   time was not a properly signed SWZ
>   file. You must ensure that you deploy
>   an Adobe-signed RSL.

You should update the shared libraries on your server, so the client to download the proper versions to run the flash application.

Comment: When you compile your project with rsl enabled, a few runtime shared libraries are generated (*.swz) besides the `swf` file. Those files should be copied to the server near your swf, so when requested they can be found.